# Weird character PHP \u00a3 instead of £

Tags: php

well I'm having a problem and this weird character is showing up '\u00a3'

it's suppose to be a " £ " symbol, but for some reason it's not doing that,anyone got any ideas why.

Comment: 0xa3 is actually £ and not €.

Comment: sorry, its yuro(£) symbol

Comment: £ is the pound (or lira) symbol. € is the yuro (or rather euro) symbol.

Answer (score 6):

Set the correct encoding of the webpage output, add this to the HEAD section of your HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```